# Proving that $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and finding a basis for $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set $W$ of all vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in \Bbb R^4$ satisfying:

$3x_1 − 2x_2 − x_3 − 4x_4 = 0$

$x_1 + x_2 − 2x_3 − 3x_4 = 0$

1. Show that $W \subset \Bbb R$
2. Find a basis for $W$.

I'm really struggling to grasp this. I know what you need to show to prove a set is a subspace. But I'm having issues showing that it's closed under Vector Addition and Scalar Multiplication.

And I don't really know how to find a basis, I know that it should span the set W and be Linearly Independent, but how do I find it.

Comment: I'm able to prove that W is not empty, further that I'm having issues.

Comment: And if anyone could give me some guidelines on how to exactly find bases, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you find the solution set for the above system of equations?

Comment: About the closure, note that if we have a two solutions of the system, then the linear combinations of the solutions are again a solution of the system.

Comment: I can solve the system of equations yes.

Comment: The reduced row echelon form of the augmented matrix for a linear system gives you all the information needed to answer such questions (about the basis of solutions to the homogeneous problem).  The first part (about $W \subset \mathbb{R}$) seems to be misstated.  Indeed you have already defined $W \subset \mathbb{R}^4$.  Perhaps the notation was meant to ask us to show $W$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm really struggling to grasp this. I know what you need to show to prove a set is a subspace. But I'm having issues showing that it's closed under Vector Addition and Scalar Multiplication.

It's not hard, but it's a matter of realizing what exactly you have to show and then writing it up nicely. Since the zero vector clearly satisfies both (homogeneous) equations, $W$ is not empty. Suppose you have two elements $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \in W$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4) \in W$; then verify:

- $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)+(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4) \in W$
- $(ka_1,ka_2,ka_3,ka_4)\in W$ for $k \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary.

Because the two equations are linear and homogeneous, this should be easy. Now for the basis:

> I've solved the system yes and gotten the various elements in terms of others (given that we have 2 equations and 4 unknowns, some elements will be written in terms of others)

Depending on which variables you chose (to solve for, in terms of the others), you should have a solution set of the form (choosing $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$):
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l} x_3 = -x_1+2x_2 \\ x_4 = x_1-x_2 \end{array}\right.$$
This means that any element of $W$ can be written in the form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\x_4 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ -x_1+2x_2 \\ x_1-x_2 \end{pmatrix}
= x_1\color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}}
+ x_2\color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix}0 \\1 \\ 2 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}}$$
So any element of $W$ can be written as a linear combination of the two vectors in blue. Note (and check) that they are linearly independent.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much. This clears up much of the confusion.

Comment: @ArshadMonsterAbrahams Alright, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two equation and there are independent you should be able to observe that then dimension of $W$ is 2.
Put $x=x_1$ and $y=x_2$ (this is only for better understanding). So we have two equations,
$$ 3x-2y=x_3+4x_4$$
$$ x+y=2x_3+3x_4$$
From these two equations solve for $x_3$ and $x_4$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ we get
$$ x_3=2y-x$$
$$ x_4=x-y$$
Hence we can see that $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x*(1,0,-1,1)+y*(0,1,2,-1)$.
Therefore $\{(1,0,-1,1),(0,1,2,-1)\}$ form a basis of $W$